# Action failed, due to server error. #laravel #FileManager #TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, tinymce, file-manager

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xcky.png)I am php programmer and use laravel and install FileManager on my project and use it by tinymce
FileManager work correctly for upload images but when I upload video (.mp4) sometimes give to me an error("Action failed, due to server error.")
I should mention I never change FileManger config in lfm.php 
and my project in localhost maybe help you for help me!
sorry for my bad English!

Answer (score 0):

Did you check within the App\ifm.php, the 'max_file_size' to the minimum you require?

Comment: yes I did


    `'should_validate_size' => false,`
    `'max_image_size' => 50000,`
    `'max_file_size' => 50000,`